# Tomcat 7 stops receiving HTTP-requests

Tags: java, apache, http, tomcat

I have a `Tomcat 7` server that receives a lot of `GET`-requests. This works very well for some time, then suddenly it stops working (after 7-8 hours).

When it stops working, I am getting this error:

> mai 06, 2015 12:47:58 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
>       INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
>        Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

All others errors after this, is just the same. I have tried to stop the get-requests, but it crashes after a while anyways. Do you have any ideas?

This is right before it crashes:

> [06/May/2015:10:47:11 +0200] "GET /ListenerServlet?request=getLastChanged&_=1430852558104 HTTP/1.1" 200 32

After the crash:

> [06/May/2015:10:47:14 +0200] "GET /ListenerServlet?request=getLastChanged&_=1430902035081 HTTP/1.1" 500 1674

After the crash, the Servlet can't get the request parameter.. that throws this nullpointer:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [RoomServlet] in context with path [] threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException
        at factory.Factory.initEditMode(Factory.java:37)
        at factory.Factory.init(Factory.java:20)
        at factory.TabsFactory.<init>(TabsFactory.java:19)
        at servlet.RoomServlet.getTabs(RoomServlet.java:285)
        at servlet.RoomServlet.doGet(RoomServlet.java:46)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

followed by:

```
mai 07, 2015 9:58:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class websocket.drawboard.DrawboardContextListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/websocket/Endpoint
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2944)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1208)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
        at websocket.drawboard.DrawboardContextListener.contextDestroyed(DrawboardContextListener.java:32)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5014)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5659)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.websocket.Endpoint
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
        ... 17 more
```

IF there is anything more I need to add, let me know! I really appreciate.

EDIT: Today was a good day, I got a new error! This might have something with the JDBC....

> The last packet successfully received from the server was 33 921 291
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   1 milliseconds ago. No operations allowed after connection closed.

Comment: have you tried to update the tomcat version? Maybe it's a bug. (i had a problem, which was solved after using a newer version of tomcat)

Comment: I am currently using the Tomcat Linux version from the apt-get.

Comment: It may be a resource issue, as your application is using web sockets. See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html for details. You may need to change the Tomcat configuration in order to avoid consuming one thread per connection for long-lived connections, for example.

Comment: @OleReidarHolm: this may not be the most current version!

Comment: did you noticed this: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.websocket.Endpoint**

Comment: I have currently done a clean install of tomcat. If the errors occurs in the morning, then I will let u know

Comment: It didn't work. I upgraded to Tomcat 7.0.61 now. Lets see what happens.
@Ben java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.websocket.Endpoint only happens once in a while, it does not happen everytime..

Comment: Didn't work. Still the same errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution to this almost by random.

There was nothing related to:

> org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process

but it was rather a JDBC problem.. the connection closed after 8 hours, and I didn't get any errors in the Servlet' for this.

The solution for me was to add some lines in my application's Context:

I added:

```
url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?autoReconnect=true"
dontTrackOpenResources="true"
testWhileIdle="true"
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="300000"
```

This is my full Context now:

```
<Context>
  <Resource name="jdbc/test" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="100" maxWait="30000"
               username="test" password="bestpassword" 
               driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?autoReconnect=true"
               removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="10"
               factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
               fairQueue="true"
               dontTrackOpenResources="true"
               testWhileIdle="true"
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="300000"
               />
</Context>
```

My server has not crashed in a week now, and I believe it wont crash again.

Comment: Has it crashed again since related to this?

Comment: Hello @Riaan. It has been 2 years and 6 months since I posted this issue, so an honest answer to this would be "I don't know". Since you reached out it would only be fair to answer based on what I remember. I remember that we tested the server for some months without a single crash. The solution was a bit clutchy.. I would never recommend a never-closing JDBC-connection, but in this case that was our only solution. 
I don't know if Tomcat has found a fix for this or not, but I'm sure that you will find something related if you google "jdbc connection closing tomcat".

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing [Apache Tomcat v7.0.53](http://olex.openlogic.com/package_versions/25029/download?package_version_id=103010&path=https%3A%2F%2Folex-secure.openlogic.com%2Fcontent%2Fprivate%2F5e6a6f0815e830bba705e79e4a0470fbee8a5880%2F%2Folex-secure.openlogic.com%2Fapache-tomcat-7.0.61.zip) or higher.

Comment: Ok, I am trying with the newest Tomcat version now (7.0.61). I will find out tomorrow if it worked. Thanks

Comment: Please ensure the websocket libraries are all in classpath , with their dependencies. This seems to be a dependency issue arising in the sequence of some request context switch

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a file descriptor leak, which could cause failure in class loading, you can check how many file descriptor are open by using [lsof](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof).